# Vintage Font Effect

Tags: fonts, vintage

[image: Original Image]

How do I copy this effect? I have tried just duplicating the text but that looks weird. Thanks!

[image: Attempt]

**EDIT:**
I threw this together - sorry about the bright colors. It showed up way brighter on here. But, yeah I feel like it just doesn't align as good as in the first picture, and it has to be diagonal instead of duplicated down, if that makes sense.

Comment: Can we see your attempted duplication?

Comment: What app? Why isn't copy, move, change color, working for you?

Comment: How does it look weird?  What do you think is wrong with your attempt? What do you mean by "doesn't align as good"? Do you realise it looks different because 1) it's a different font, and 2) the original has a black stroke around the lettering, and 3) the letters overlap vertically in the original?  Also what software are you using?

Comment: and 4) it was probably hand-drawn

Answer (score 5):

In Illustrator you can use 3D effect Extrude. The extrusion is available also in CorelDraw and in CAD programs.

By extruding one gives an apparent thickness to a text or another flat shape. Here several extruded versions are piled.

Also some flat shapes are drawed into the spaces between the chatacters.

I inserted a simple example in Illustrator:

[image]

1. A text (orange, no stroke and blue with black stroke)
2. The orange is extruded, a green copy was made (see the dialog for the 3D settings)
3. The extrudes have their appearances expanded, all subshapes are united in the pathfinder panel and have got the same fill. The extrusion is no more apparent, the shapes only look out stretched. But they have just that what's missing from a pile of flat(= non-extruded) texts.
4. A black stroke is added to both extrudes.
5. The extrusions and the non-extruded blue version are piled. Blue covers inconsistent black strokes in the orange shape.

The next image has a wide overall stroke and a background:

[image]

The overall stroke has been added to an united copy of the pile.